# Editing a bookmark throws run time error 5941 if code is run for a second time

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error, bookmarks

I have a VBA application, which generates a document named document1.

I can run the application once. If I keep document1 open and run the application next time (document2 generation in process) I am facing the below error,
[image]

Upon clicking Debug it highlights the below code,
[image]

The bookmark strBookmark highlighted in the code exists.

Comment: Are you sure that `docThisDoc` is the correct document?

Comment: Please add your code as text into your post instead of an image. We're not going to sit here typing code in for you we need to be able to copy/paste it

Comment: The error is telling you that the `strBookmark` Bookmark does not exist in the `docThisDoc` Document. If you believe it does exist, that is likely because, at the point that line of code runs, either `strBookmark` is not the text you think it is or `docThisDoc` is not the Document you think it is. As you have not included the code that assigns values to these two variables then it is impossible to be more specific. You could try adding this line before the line that errors: `Debug.Print "'" & strBookmark & "'", "'" & docThisDoc.Name & "'"` and reply back with the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you replace the text of a bookmark, Word generally destroys the bookmark. That is certainly the case when you select the bookmark and use .TypeText to replace its text.

So you have to recreate the bookmark, or you will get an error the next time through if, as in this case, you leave the document open.

The simplest change you could make here would be to do this

```
docThisDoc.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Select
Selection.Text = strData
Selection.Bookmarks.Add(strBookmark)
```

The problem with using .TypeText is that the Selection moves so that it ends up at the end of the text, so the a Selection.Bookmarks.Add would create the bookmark in the wrong place.

Comment: That is only true if the bookmarked range encloses text, i.e. it isn't of zero length. However, the most sensible thing to advise the OP would be to avoid using selection and use `.Range.Text` instead.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt. Yes, I know. Probably worth expanding later, but IMO it was enough for starters. BTW, I was surprised this wasn't an obvious duplicate but do you think there is a good close match?

Comment: ***If*** the bookmark is the issue then a search for `[ms-word][vba] bookmark` would certainly bring up some answers. However, it is unclear at this stage whether that is the issue. `docThisDoc` for example appears to be a public variable whose value may persist beyond its purpose.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt It can't be clear until the OP has done some experiments, IMO. Ideally shouldn't be the case on a Q&A site but...