# MS Word VBA Application throwing run time error 5941

Tags: vba, collections, ms-word, runtime-error

I have a VBA application, which when run generates a document named document1 and when I run the application for the first time it runs without any problem however if I keep the document1 open and run the application next time(immediately after clicking the template) I am facing the below error,

[image]

Upon clicking Debug it highlights the below code,

[image]

Please refer below for the full code.

```
Sub LoadPurposeCodes()
    Dim thisTable As table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim strCell As String
    Dim lngLastSection As Long

    Protect_UnProtect
    **Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks -- Tried adding this** 
    lngLastSection = docThisDoc.Sections.Count
    Set thisTable = docThisDoc.Sections(lngLastSection).Range.Tables(1)

    ReDim aTypes(2, 0)
    ReDim aPurpose(1, 0)

    iRows = thisTable.Rows.Count
    j = -1
    For i = 2 To iRows
        strCell = TrimCell(thisTable.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text)
 
        If strCell <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve aTypes(2, j)
            aTypes(0, j) = strCell
            aTypes(1, j) = CStr(i - 2)  ' from
        End If
        ReDim Preserve aPurpose(1, i - 2)
        **On Error GoTo 0   --- Tried adding this one**
        aPurpose(0, i - 2) = TrimCell(thisTable.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text)
        aPurpose(1, i - 2) = TrimCell(thisTable.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text)
        aTypes(2, j) = CStr(i - 2)
    Next i

    Protect_UnProtect
End Sub
```

I have tried adding the below snippets as few approaches to resolve however it didn't serve the purpose.

Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks, and On Error GoTo 0

Is this related MS 365 issue? if not your help in pointing out what has caused the issue and related fix is much appreciated. I am happy to provide more details related to the issue whenever needed.

```
Sub Protect_UnProtect()

    If docThisDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set docThisDoc = ActiveDocument
    End If

    With docThisDoc
    If .ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
        .Unprotect Password:=LOAN_PASSWORD
    Else
        .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:=LOAN_PASSWORD
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code `TrimCell()`.

Comment: Does your table contain merged cells?  There may be no `Cell(i, 2)` in the table.

Comment: Is it linked to your issue [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407486/)? We still don't know what docThisDoc is. In both case you mention creating a new document, maybe there is some issue there?

Comment: Function TrimCell(thisCell As String)

    TrimCell = Left(thisCell, Len(thisCell) - 2)
    
End Function

Comment: Public docThisDoc As Document

Comment: The pattern is same but the issue here occurring with the table.